# How to read ANY csv file, not just a specific one, in a c++ program

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to do my homework (fairly new to c++) and it requires me to create a program that will read any .csv files from yahoo finance. I know how to read a specific file, but i do not know how to generalize this

I have tried searching on google but nothing really answered my question.

this is what i did to read a specific file

```
ifstream file;
file.open("GLD.csv");
if (file.is_open()) {
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            cout << line << endl;
```

we are required to change the csv file in the folder of our main .cpp file, so the file name is not going to be "GLD.csv" all the time. How would i "generalize" the reading of the input to different .csv files? thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification

Comment: Have you looked at existing questions including [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140)?  Please, also read this [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Do you have these .csv files on hand? Or do you have to scrape them from somewhere?

Comment: See #1 from @alvinalvord's answer. Then `int i = 1; while (argv[i]) { file.open (argv[i]); ... i++ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 3 ways to do this:

1. Use command line arguments. You can get the command line arguments by defining main as `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {}` wherein argc is the count of arguments and argv is the values. So when you run the program you can just do `program.exe filename.csv`
2. Scan for the input filename. `cin >> filename;`
3. Get the current directory and get all the csv files. Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) on how to get the files in a directory.

Comment: Helpful to remind that the first argument `argv[0]` is always the program name being executed so the first user supplied argument will start at index `1` (e.g. `argv[1]`).